# MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR

Tags: c#, message-queue, ibm-mq, mq

```
//snippet
MQEnvironment.properties = GetConnectionProperties(); 

_queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManager);  

//end of snippet

    private Hashtable GetConnectionProperties()
    {
        Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
        properties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, Environment.UserName);
        properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, MQHostname);
        properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, MQPortNumber);
        properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, MqChannel);            
        properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);            

        if (_useSSL)
        {
            properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY, CipherSuite);
            properties.Add(MQC.SSL_PEER_NAME_PROPERTY, SslPeerName);              
            properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, CipherSpec);
            properties.Add(MQC.SSL_FIPS_REQUIRED_PROPERTY, FipsRequired);
            properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, SslKeyRepository);        
        }

        return properties;
    }

throws {"MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR"}
```

the sslkeyRepository is just a directory location which contains .tab .arm .crl .crt .jks .kdb .rdb .sth files

Any ideas what i am missing here?

Answer (score 4):

SslKeyRepository must point to a .kdb file and not to a directory as you have done. For example a client application will code for certificate store property as:

```
properties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, "C:\\MyApp\\SSL\\client_certstore");
```

Also note that I have not suffixed the file extension to keystore file name. MQ client will automatically add the ".kdb" extension. Please see this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q099920_.htm?lang=en) for more details.

Also you need to set only SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY in your application. You don't set SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY. See the table [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031290_.htm?lang=en).

Comment: You need to include the name of the kdb file also. Just the directory is not enough